# Xamarin SimpleAudioPlayer returns System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xamarin, audio

I am trying to play a .wav file in Xamarin.

The file is found but I get the below execption using this code. How is that possible as it does find the emailalert.wav file and should get a stream?
**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Happens on this line:

```js
audio.Load(stream);
```

```js
        public void Play()
        {
            String path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            String filename2 = "Folder1/emailalert.wav"; String filenameB = Path.Combine(path, filename2);
          
            if (File.Exists(filenameB))
            {
                var stream = GetStreamFromFile(filenameB);
                var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
                audio.Load(stream);
                audio.Play();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what does the stack trace show?

Comment: @Jason, thank you for your help! I found a solution and posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to embedd the file directly under the Resources folder and then using this code. I also in the Properties of the .wav file choosed "Build Action" and "Embedded Resource".

Now this code plays the file nicely:

```js
        public void Play()
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
            foreach (string resource in resources)
            {
                if (resource.Contains("emailalert.wav"))
                {
                    Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        var audio = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
                        audio.Load(stream);
                        audio.Play(); break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How would you play list of songs? I treid use foreach and for loop to play a list, but it will not stop and play each track, but iterate very fast to the end of loop and play only the last one.
I used thread sleeping for duration of track, but it will disable all system and no button will work to go to next or pervious track.
Any solution please?